# Which flag has the value 603979776 (Android)?

Tags: java, android, push-notification

I decompile old Android-library, and want to make a new one with updates.
After decompile I have this lines:

```
Intent notificationIntent = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(context.getPackageName());
notificationIntent.setFlags(603979776);
```

And I get error on `setFlags` method - it needs to be one of `Intent` flags.

So, what I need to use instead of `603979776`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

603979776 expressed in hex is 0x24000000 thus FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP + FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP (0x4000000 + 0x20000000).